# Adobe Illustrator CS5.5 - repair borders after image trace

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace, borders

I'm creating a pattern design in illustrator. I used the trace feature but I'm not happy with the outcome. The tracing smoothed out the borders too much and I lost the square "rocky edge" look I'm going for. I tried using a custom border to overcome that, but that didn't work or better said, what I tried with using borders was not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not happy with the outcome of a trace, do the trace again with different settings. You can get dramatically different results from a trace depending on what settings you use. You don’t want to lose key elements of the design during the trace. Basically, don’t stop tracing until you are happy with the results.